# How do i join multiple mesh's into one without destroying the original shapes that ive made with modifyers

Tags: mesh, mirror-modifier

Joining the items that make up the fridge to try and make one model destroys the look I'm trying to get. I'm just looking for any way I can combine these meshes to have the first pictures look
[image: The fridge I'm trying to achive]

[image: A wireframe of the meshes I'm trying to combine]

[image: What i get]

Comment: Many modifiers can be isolated to only affect vertex groups.  Suggest adding more detail, eg a picture showing the modifier stack(s). Or maybe a  blend file.   In joining objects the modifiers of the active are used for the whole.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can keep modifiers if you join objects into one because how Blender works. If you join 10 objects then final object will have properties and modifiers of active object that goes as base.

You cannot join meshes and keep all modifiers, you can try to use vertex groups... Give each object vertex group over all vertices. Join your object and then add modifiers again and allow them to work only on specific vertex groups...

Other way is only to finish all details you want while separated, apply all modifiers on all objects and only THEN join them in one object